# When use TwitterKit the function logOut don't work

Tags: objective-c

I need to logout user from my app.

I use TwitterKit/Fabric to logIn.

```
[TwitterKit logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error)
{

}];
```

and try to logOut with this :

```
[TwitterKit logOut];
```

- the TwitterKit login set the user account in the iPhone -> Settings -> Twitter and
  when I try to login again logInWithCompletion automatically the logIn the user
- when I use logOut nothing happens.

Would love to hear suggestions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
[TwitterKit logOut];
```

It Deletes the local Twitter user session from this app. This will not remove the system Twitter account nor make a network request to invalidate the session.

ref:https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios-reference/twitter

Comment: Even the Twitter user session  [TwitterKit logOut] don't logOut.